# Flatten recursive taxonomic table (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, recursion, ncbi

I'm fairly new to Oracle and completely new to taxonomic data, so please bear with me...

I have a large table of data that looks like this:

```
| tax_id | value |
|:------:|:-----:|
|   211  |  56.4 |
|   326  |  2.7  |
|   47   |  89.6 |
|   569  |  43.2 |
|    …   |   …   |
```

The `tax_id` column usually specifies the **species**, but sometimes it's more generic e.g. specifying the genus, order or some higher level in the taxonomic tree.

**I'd like to calculate summary statistics by aggregating the `value` column at different taxonomic levels**. To do this I need to join-in additional taxonomic information, so I've downloaded a copy of the `ncbi_nodes` table from the [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) taxonomic database. This table is large (about 1.5 million rows) and it looks something like this:

```
| tax_id | parent_id | rank |
|:------:|:---------:|:----:|
|   211  |    209    |   4  |
|    2   |   131567  |  28  |
|   209  |   72293   |   8  |
|  1224  |     2     |  24  |
|  29547 |   68525   |  21  |
|  68525 |    1224   |  23  |
|  72293 |   213849  |  12  |
| 131567 |     1     |   0  |
| 213849 |   29547   |  17  |
```

The `rank` column takes integer values from 0 to 28 and it specifies the taxonomic level for each `tax_id`. Lower ranks specify more detailed taxonomic levels (e.g. rank 4 is species, rank 8 is genus, etc.), except rank=0, which corresponds to "no rank/undefined".

This table has a recursive/hierarchical structure and I'm not sure how best to use it to aggregate my data. My initial idea is to try to "flatten" it so the ranks appear as columns, something like this:

```
| tax_id | 0      | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4   | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8   | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12    | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17     | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21    | 22 | 23    | 24   | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
|--------|--------|---|---|---|-----|---|---|---|-----|---|----|----|-------|----|----|----|----|--------|----|----|----|-------|----|-------|------|----|----|----|----|
| 211    | 131567 |   |   |   | 211 |   |   |   | 209 |   |    |    | 72293 |    |    |    |    | 213849 |    |    |    | 29547 |    | 68525 | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 209    | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   | 209 |   |    |    | 72293 |    |    |    |    | 213849 |    |    |    | 29547 |    | 68525 | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 72293  | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    | 72293 |    |    |    |    | 213849 |    |    |    | 29547 |    | 68525 | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 213849 | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    |       |    |    |    |    | 213849 |    |    |    | 29547 |    | 68525 | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 29547  | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    |       |    |    |    |    |        |    |    |    | 29547 |    | 68525 | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 68525  | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    |       |    |    |    |    |        |    |    |    |       |    | 68525 | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 1224   | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    |       |    |    |    |    |        |    |    |    |       |    |       | 1224 |    |    |    | 2  |
| 2      | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    |       |    |    |    |    |        |    |    |    |       |    |       |      |    |    |    | 2  |
| 131567 | 131567 |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |     |   |    |    |       |    |    |    |    |        |    |    |    |       |    |       |      |    |    |    |    |
```

I could then join this output to my original data and calculate summary statistics by using `GROUP BY` on any of the `rank` columns.

My question:

**How can I "flatten" the recursive table structure into something like the above, please?**

I've been reading about recursive queries and CTEs, but I'm pretty new to Oracle (and SQL), so I'm not sure yet whether this is really what I want. In particular, does it matter that different `tax_ids` have different rank information (i.e. not all taxa have entries for all 29 ranks, as in the example above)?

Any SQL hints would be much appreciated, and even knowing whether recursive queries are the right or wrong thing to follow up would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of ways to accomplish this, but I could write a book. The question I have is whether there are a finite number of "columns" in the representation.  You could build a view based on max() on unions, you could assemble the query as the output of a stored proc, you could create a flattened based on connect by.  There are multiple answers to this question.

Comment: @T Gray. Thanks for your comment. The maximum number of columns is 29, but for most organisms (i.e. most tax_ids) the number of "levels" with data is fewer. The example above for `tax_id=211` is fairly typical: rank 4 (species) > rank 8 (genus) > rank 12 (family) > rank 17 (order) > rank 21 (class) > rank 23 (sub-phylum) > rank 24 (phylum) > rank 28 (superkingdom) > rank 0 (no class). Some organisms have a complete record for all 29 levels (1 to 28, then 0), but there are never more than this. I hope I've understood your question :-)